# INNER JOIN table1.id = table2.id and col1 = null and col2 = not null

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a query like this:

```
his = His.where(id: self.id)
```

Comment: this is not readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
class LearningHistory < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  scope :completed, ->{ where.not(completed_at: nil) }
```

Then:

```
answer_histories = AnswerHistory.where(slide_id: self.slide_id)
 .joins(:material_progress).where(material_progresses: {site_id: site.id})
 .joins(:learning_history)
 .merge(LearningHistory.completed)    
 .where(MaterialProgress.arel_table[:learning_history_id]
 .eq(AnswerHistory.arel_table[:learning_history_id]))
```

Comment: and in general, I recommend you move everything to scopes and use merge